# How to put a const weak_ptr into a STL container

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a class *TileManager* that manages the lifetime of objects and therefore holds a shared_ptr on them:

```
class TileManager {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Tile>> tiles;
}
```

Now I have another class *Map* which holds non-owning references to the objects managed by *TileManager*:

```
class Map {
private:
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<const Tile>> tiles;
}
```

My problem is: I don't want the *Map* class to be able to manipulate the smart pointers to *Tile*. Therefore I would like to make the pointers inside the *vector* const:

```
class Map {
private:
    std::vector<const std::weak_ptr<const Tile>> tiles;
}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to put const objects into a STL container.

Anyone know a solution? Maybe a completely different design?

Comment: What do you mean when you say _I don't want the Map class to be able to manipulate the smart pointers to Tile_? What kind of manipulation / operation is it you'd like to prevent from happening?

Comment: I don't want it to *reset* the pointer.

Comment: I realise this may be a change to your design, but: Wouldn't it be a good idea to actually _allow_ the `Map` class to reset pointers, but make sure that all of the member functions of `Map` that return some of the weak pointers only return them as either copy (`std::weak_ptr<const Tile>`) or const-reference (`const std::weak_ptr<const Tile> &`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements stored in a `vector` cannot be `const` because they must be assignable.  The only way that the `vector` could "manipulate" the pointers in any observable way would be to destroy the last `weak_ptr` to a given object which would cause the control block for the corresponding `shared_ptr` to be deallocated (assuming there are no other `shared_ptr`'s that still reference it).

In short, you can safely store non-`const` `weak_ptr`'s in a vector.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, you could use `std::set`.  Since the only way to access data from a set only provides const references or const iterators, you cannot directly manipulate the values.

To do this, you would use

`std::set<std::weak_ptr<const Tile>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<const Tile>>>`.

The other, non-technological solution, is to do it by design, since it is a private member of what presumably is your class: simply say in your class design 'Don't reset or overwrite the weak pointers'.

Comment: Since we're talking C++11, please use a `std::unordered_set` atleast, which has O(1) access to the values.

Comment: @Xeo:  I do not believe `std::hash<T>` is specialized for `std::weak_ptr<T>`, while `std::owner_less<T>` is.  The standard only specifies the hash for `shared_ptr<T>` and `unique_ptr<T>`.  And without direct access to the underlying control data for the `weak_ptr`, it would be difficult to obtain a hash that does not change even when the weak_ptr expires.